# Wrap user req in a custom API in redux-saga for server side

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

In a universal app that handle authentication, we have to consider each user with his own cookies. 
So we need to store his initial request object to be able to decorate his future API calls with his cookies.
I don't see how to handle it with redux-saga, i guess the work should be done in a custom middleware to inject an object that wrap the user request object into each saga, at least i think it would do the job, but i don't see how to achieve it entirely.

I was thinking about something like that:

```js
export function* loadUser(action, api) { // Inject the object that wrap the initial user request object here
  try {
    const user = yield call(api.loadUser, action.payload); // So the request would be decorated behind this call
    yield put(actions.loadUserSuccess(user));
  } catch(e) {
    yield put(actions.loadUserFail(e));
  }
}

export default function* rootUserSagas() {
  yield* takeLatest(LOAD_USER_REQUEST, loadUser);
}
```

I guess there is something to do when creating the store

```js
export function configureStore(initialState = {}, req) {
  const api = new Api(req);

  // Then what to do with the api object to get it back into sagas?

  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
  );

  sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

  return store;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the api object to the run function

```
  sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga, api)
```

Then pass around the object to child sagas

```
export default function* rootUserSagas(api) {
    yield* takeLatest(LOAD_USER_REQUEST, loadUser, api);
}

// loadUser will receive the action in the last position
function* loadUser(api, action) { ... }
```

Comment: This answer in the documentation: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/index.html#middlewarerunsaga-args